# jQuery variable is false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making "Log in" system.. First table I'am checking **input value**.. 
if exists **@**... In the first function **url** variable is working perfect... But in second function **url** variable is returning always **name** value, the interesting thing is **successET** variable is still dynamic when I am trying to use it in second function...

Here the result is **successET** variable is successfully dynamic, but **var** variable is static, when I am trying to use it in another function;

This is the first function:

```
$("#login_username_next").click(function(){
            containsET = $('#login_username_mail_pass').val();
            if (~containsET.indexOf("@")) {url = "email";} else {url = "name"};
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "Model/functionsPHP/login/check"+url+".php",
                data:'data='+containsET,
                success: function(data){
                                if(data !=="0"){
                                successET = data;


                                            } 
                } 

        });   });
```

THis is second function

```
$("body").on("click", "#login_password_next", function(){  
    alert(url); //Here url is "name" always, but in 1st func is dynamic
        containsPASS = $('#login_username_mail_pass').val();
                $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Model/functionsPHP/login/login.php",
            data:'data='+successET+"&pass="+containsPASS+"&type="+url,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data)
                                    } 


        });

        });
```

Maybe the short answer should be > **How to pass variables from one function to another function ?** Thanks for your interest :)

HERE is my HTML:

```
<div id="logreg_modal">
    <div id="logreg_header">
        <div id="logreg_login">
            <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>&nbsp;Log in
        </div>
        <div id="logreg_join">
            <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i></i>&nbsp;Join us
        </div>
        <div id="logreg_close">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>Hide
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="logreg_content">
        <div class="logreg_content_prev">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>  
        </div>
        <div id="logreg_content_input" data-placeholder="Username or e-Mail" >
            <input id="login_username_mail_pass"> </input>
        </div>

        <div class="logreg_content_next" id="login_username_next">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't the most elegant solution, but it'll work: declare the variable on global scope, then it'll be available to both functions.

Comment: You have more than one issue in your code. Could you provide the HTML of the elements that you reference in the code, so to provide enough information to reproduce the issue?

Comment: ofcurse, now i will edit and add my html :)

Comment: @DanielBeck, from the current behaviour it is clear that `url` is already global.

Comment: True, the **url** is already global, but returns same value when trying to use it in another function... beybe this is becouse **if else statement** ?

Comment: Where is `login_password_next` in your HTML?

Comment: Ah, you're right @trincot, I misread.

Comment: @trincot This is in my 1st function, but i didn't add ... on click **login_username_next**, change it to **login_password_next**

Comment: I don't understand? Do you mean you have more HTML with `login_password_next`? If so, please add it to your question?

Comment: `$('#login_username_next').attr('id','login_password_next');` this is in first function just i am changing the html...

Comment: Exactly where in your first function (this is important). Could you update the question and add this code?

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one issue, and maybe a second:

- As you change the `id` of the input element, you must realise that the `click` handler which you already bound to that element, stays active. So after the switch, you'll have both functions responding to the click, which destroys the first results you had. The solution is to also make your first click handler a delegated one (just like the second).
- Ajax calls only produce a response asynchronously, so make sure you *only* adapt the page (HTML) once you have received the Ajax  response (different from "0"). At the time of writing you did not provide enough code to see where exactly you update the page.

Here is suggested code:

```
var successET, url;

$("body").on("click", "#login_username_next", function(){
    var containsET = $('#login_username_mail_pass').val();
    // Correctly compare indexOf to -1:
    url = containsET.indexOf("@") > -1 ? "email" : "name";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Model/functionsPHP/login/check"+url+".php",
        data:'data='+containsET,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data === "0") {
                alert('user name not found');
                return;
            }
            // Only now change the input screen, when you have an answer:
            $('#login_username_next').attr('id','login_password_next');
            // more code follows here to update the page
            // ...
        }
    });
});

$("body").on("click", "#login_password_next", function(){  
    var containsPASS = $('#login_username_mail_pass').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Model/functionsPHP/login/login.php",
        data:'data='+successET+"&pass="+containsPASS+"&type="+url,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('second request returns: ', data);
        }
    });
});
```